# Grep a file and save the result to variable synchronously using Gulp

Tags: grep, gulp

I have this case. I need to grep a file for some RegEx and the result string (or array of strings) I need to save to variable for later use. And this has to be achieved using Gulp.

It should look like this in my idea:

```
var line;
gulp.task('grep', function(callback) {
    line = someCoolSyncFunction('/needle/', './haystack.txt');
    callback();
});
gulp.task('useIt', ['grep'], function() {
    console.log(line);
});
```

Important is this **someCoolSyncFunction** to be synchronous and to handle file on physical/virtual file system, not the Vinyl file.

Is there a way to do this using Gulp? Or any other approach to achieve similar effect?

PS: to explain the reason, I need to extract version number from Debian package changelog and insert it to configuration file inside the package during the build process.

Thanks a lot.

Vit